# AWK replace all but one digit

Tags: regex, awk, split, gsub

I have a file in this format:

```
A,C 0|1 0|2 1|2
```

What I need now is this:

```
A   0|1 0|0 1|0
C   0|0 0|1 0|1
```

So, I split the lines at first which is not a problem.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{n=split($1,obs,",");for (i=1;i<=n;i++){$1=obs[i];print}}'
```

But now I need to delete the 2s in the first line and delete the 1s in the second and even replace the 2s in the second line by ones.

I hope this is understandable. The Numbers refer to the A(1) and C(2).
My idea was use gsub and to replace all digits by zero except the digit of the current line.

But there are two problems I cannot solve:

1.The following is not working (for line 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{n=split($1,obs,",");for (i=1;i<=n;i++){$1=obs[i];for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){gsub(/[1-9[^2]]/,0,$j)};print}}'
```

Shouldn't this match all digits but 2?

2.Even if this would work I would need to replace the number in the regex by a variable (current line number).

Any ideas on this?

EDIT:
It could be more complex like this:
Input

```
A,C,G,GA    0|1 0|2 1|2 2|3 4|0
```

Desired Output:

```
A   0|1 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0
C   0|0 0|2 0|1 1|0 0|0
A   0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0
GA  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|0
```

Comment: I cannot get the logic of requirement. You used `split` on `$1` later loop through it, so it could have more than two strings sep by the comma. Can you explain a bit what's the rule of the conversion? better with more examples?

Comment: This is genotype information. So there are chnages in the DNA sequence of people. For Example one could have the letter (nucleotide) A or C on this position. Each field with 0|0 0|1 and so on is one person. So what I want to do is split this lines, so that there is one line for the A and one for the C. But this means: In the first line (nuceotide A) I have to delete all 2s (2|0 2|1...) because they refer to the C. In the second line I have to delete the ones, because they refer to the A AND replace the 2 by 1s, because the first (only) Nucleotide here is now the C.

Comment: in 2nd line you didn't "delete" 1s, you replaced `1` by `0`. In 1st line, you deleted `2`s.

Comment: well... you removed original example....

Comment: Yes i made it shorter, so that it is easier to see. And YES I replaced it by 0, whis is what i meant by "deleted" sorry.

Comment: In your second example, with the 4 nucleotides, why is there a 2 in the second line of the expected output (or only one occurrence of 2, not three of them)?

Answer (score 1):

For the general case:

```
awk '{
    n = split($1,a,",")
    rest = substr($0, length($1)+1)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        regex = "[0-" i-1 i+1 "-9]"
        x = rest
        gsub(regex, "0", x)
        gsub(i, "1", x)
        print a[i], x
    }
}' << END
A,C,G,GA    0|1 0|2 1|2 2|3 4|0
END
```

```
A     0|1 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0
C     0|0 0|1 0|1 1|0 0|0
G     0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0
GA     0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think i have to check if there are more than 8 items in my files.

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
 awk -F"\t", -v OFS="\t" 
    '{n=split($1,a,",")}n==2{$1=a[1];t=$0;gsub(/2/,"0",t);print t;
                             $1=a[2];gsub(/1/,"0");gsub(/2/,"1");print}' file
```

this handles only `X,Y` case, that is, one pair in `$1`.

test, (In  my test `f`, it is space separated, not `<tab>`, so no `-F.. -v OFS...`):

```
kent$  cat f
A,C 0|1 0|2 1|2

kent$  awk  '{n=split($1,a,",")}n==2{$1=a[1];t=$0;gsub(/2/,0,t);print t;$1=a[2];gsub(/1/,"0");gsub(/2/,"1");print}' f
A 0|1 0|0 1|0
C 0|0 0|1 0|1
```

Comment: This is not working for me. In the first line only the first letter is printed and in the second line I need to replace the 2s by 1s also. Which is not a problem but, this only works if I know how many lines I have to split, but it could be something like 10 different types. I add this as an example above.

Comment: @user3793311 I added test and output. pls check the codes again.

Comment: @user3793311 if you want to do with `X,Y,Z,A,B,C....` in $1 case, it is also possible. then we need loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I will try it with loops then. I just thought it would be nice to replace all digits but the one from this line with 0. But to get it done fast I will go for the looping. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the stray 2 in the example output for the second example input is a mistake (it should be a 1), then the problem is to convert the input:

```
A,C,G,GA    0|1 0|2 1|2 2|3 4|0
```

to the desired output:

```
A   0|1 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0
C   0|0 0|1 0|1 1|0 0|0
A   0|0 0|0 0|0 0|1 0|0
GA  0|0 0|0 0|0 0|0 1|0
```

In conjunction with the other example, where there were just two items in the list and 3 pairs of numbers after it, it is clear that the number of columns in the output is not fixed.

AFAICT, the goal is split the first field into N fields, and then to generate one line of output for each of the N fields.  The output line for field *n* contains 0 whenever the number is not *n*, and 1 when the number is *n*. For simplicity, assume that there won't be more than 9 items in the list (you have to use more complex regular expressions if the numbers can have double digits).

Translated into `awk`, that becomes:

```
awk '{ N = split($1, code, ",")
       $1 = ""
       tail = $0
       for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
       {
           line = code[i] "  " tail
           for (j = 1; j <= N; j++)
           {
               if (j != i)
                   gsub(j, "0", line)
           }
           gsub(i, "1", line)
           print line
       }
     }'
```

Except perhaps for spacing, this produces the desired output from the given input.  It would be possible to 'fix' the spacing (if it needs fixing) with something like:

```
awk '{ N = split($1, code, ",")
       $1 = ""
       tail = $0
       for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
       {
           line = tail
           for (j = 1; j <= N; j++)
           {
               if (j != i)
                   gsub(j, "0", line)
           }
           gsub(i, "1", line)
           printf("%-4s %s\n", code[i], line
       }
     }'
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks good. However I came up with a very similar solution before I saw your response (I was traveling with no internet connection). I will post it here an I will try your version, perhaps it is better because mine has more "loops".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "own" solution, quit similar to the one of Jonathan Leffer:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{
    line=$0
    n=split($1,obs,",")
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
        $0=line
        $1=obs[i]
        for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){
            for(k=1;k<=n;k++){
                if(k!=i){
                    gsub(k,"0",$j)
                    gsub(i,"1",$j)
                }
            }
        }
        print
    }
}'
```

Comment: Your answer is essentially the same as mine, except that it does the `gsub(i, "1", $j)` mapping N-1 times instead of just once (which is sufficient).  That `gsub()` call could be moved out of the innermost (`for (k…)`) loop.  Well done.

Comment: You are right! What i didn't told you was, that there are more fields in the inputfile. Because of this I have to make sure that the gsub only works on the right fields. But thanks for all of your help.